# How to grab ALL html source from an instance of internetexplorer object with VB6?

Tags: html

I want to get ALL of the html from an open webpage on my computer using vB6. The webpage has multiple frames. I don't know html and I am not sure what frames are so please take that into account with your answer. I simply want the html in a text file in any text format so i can search through it for data. The 'IE show source' has all the info i need, but how to get that with a vb6 program? Most web searches I have done come up with how to get the html by downloading using an url and that wont work for me. I need the html from an open instance of IE. Preferably using the internetexplorer object with VB6. Thanks.

Comment: [WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Might this fullfill the condition?:
[http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=238876](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=238876)

Answer (score 1):

Save the `HTML`'s source code.
Add it to the environment variables and open `VB6`:

1. Open a new project/file
2. Include your saved html
3. Drag an drop the boxes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Winsock control? I think that is what your looking for.